# wifi to etho port

Tags: static-ip

I have trawled the internet for 3 months and failed. Maybe I am dim.
My target is to share my wifi internet to the Ethernet port. Cant find a solution that works.
So splitting my questions up.
I want my Pi3 to allocate an IP address to my laptop via the Pi3 eth0.
I have tried various versions of the following in sudo nano /etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
interface=eth0                              # Use interface eth0
listen-address=192.168.0.100                # Explicitly specify the address to listen on
bind-interfaces                             # Bind to the interface to make sure we aren't sending thi$
server=8.8.8.8                              # Forward DNS requests to Google DNS
domain-needed                               # Don't forward short names
bogus-priv                                  # Never forward addresses in the non-routed address spaces$
dhcp-range=192.168.0.101,192.168.0.150,12h  # Assign IP addresses between 172.24$
```

but doesn't work.

The IP address of my wifi connection is 
10.0.2.5.
I have tried changing the code above to a nearer IP address but no change.

This is the only config change from a newly installed raspian stretch config.

Help!

Ian

Comment: google `rpi3 bridge`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share internet wifi to ethernet](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95267/share-internet-wifi-to-ethernet)

Comment: You have asked a question as *Milliways* noted. That question seems to dangling now. I have suggested two times [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95267/share-internet-wifi-to-ethernet#comment154892_95267) and [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95267/share-internet-wifi-to-ethernet#comment154940_95267) to take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help). Maybe I could help you but why should I believe that you honor my effort if you don't know how things work here?

Comment: Up to you if you want to help. Suspect by your answer you can't. I am here to learn. If I make mistakes on the forum, that's how I learn.  The question only dangles as I have not found a solution.